# Android Webview SCROLL

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview, i am loading it with data, its in scrollview, i want to block scrolling when it scroll down to end of displayed content, i have tried javascript approach with adding div at end of content, getting it position and checking is scroll beyond it but it didtnt worked out, values returned by my script are wrong, getcontentheight is wrong too, and i am really pissed off, how is that possible that webview can scroll beyond it contents??? is this default behavoiur? i just want to display normal html, and i dont want to scroll beyond it

Comment: Can you post your xml file? And I don't think you have to put WebView in scrollview, because webview can have scroll bars if contents are more to display at screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just use only WebView without scrollView and use layout_height wrap_content.